# How to increase file size upload limit in spring boot using embedded tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, embedded-tomcat

I am try to upload the file using my spring boot API. The function is working fine when I am using small file (less than 1 MB), but when I upload large file it gives me an exception. I am using embedded Tomcat server.

```
Maximum upload size exceeded; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field file exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576 bytes.
```

I have tried the following code in my files but every time I am getting the error

**1. application.property**

```
server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=100MB
server.tomcat.max-http-post-size=100MB
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true 
spring.servlet.multipart.fileSizeThreshold=100MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=100MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=100MB
```

I have also tried

```
spring.servlet.multipart.maxFileSize=100MB
spring.servlet.multipart.maxRequestSize=100MB
```

**2. The below is my file uploading code**

```
public RestDTO uploadFile(MultipartFile file, String subPath) {

    if (file.isEmpty()) {
        return new RestFailure("Failed to store empty file");
    }

    try {
        String fileName = new Date().getTime() + "_" + file.getOriginalFilename();
        String filePath = uploadPath + subPath + fileName;
        if (Objects.equals(file.getOriginalFilename(), "blob")) {
            filePath += ".png";
            fileName += ".png";
        }
        File uploadDir = new File(uploadPath + subPath);
        if (!uploadDir.exists()) {
            uploadDir.mkdirs();
        }
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
        output.write(file.getBytes());
        LOGGER.info("File path : " + filePath);

        MediaInfoDTO mediaInfoDTO = getThumbnailFromVideo(subPath, fileName);

        String convertedFileName = convertVideoToMP4(subPath, fileName);

        System.out.println("---------------->" + convertedFileName);

        return new RestData<>(new MediaDetailDTO(mediaInfoDTO.getMediaPath(), convertedFileName,
                mediaInfoDTO.getMediaType(), mediaInfoDTO.getMediaCodec(), mediaInfoDTO.getWidth(),
                mediaInfoDTO.getHeight(), mediaInfoDTO.getDuration()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.info("Can't upload file: " + e.getMessage());
        return new RestFailure("Failed to store empty file");
    }
}
```

but every time I got the same exception.

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot are you using<?

Comment: I am using spring boot 2.1.7

Comment: `spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size` and `spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size` just work for spring boot 2.1.7. try setting these both to -1 (basically unlimited)

Comment: I have used that spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=-1 and spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=-1. Still not working

Comment: updated answer with correct ByteSize

Answer (score 9):

Apart from comment might I suggest creating a `@Bean` for Factory `MultipartConfigurationElement`
This basically should override other restrictions if you have any from TomCat side.

```java
@Bean
public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
    MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
    factory.setMaxFileSize(DataSize.ofBytes(100000000L));
    factory.setMaxRequestSize(DataSize.ofBytes(100000000L));
    return factory.createMultipartConfig();
}
```

Here `DataSize` is of type `org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize`

Reference https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11284

Another issue I suspect could be from TomCat `maxSwallowSize` see Baeldung's point #5 if above does not work.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-maxuploadsizeexceeded

Comment: There's no need to do this. Spring Boot will auto-configure a `MultipartConfigElement` using the `spring.servlet.multipart.*` properties.

Answer (score 2):

After reviewing many examples and after several tests with no results. I have managed to solve the problem with the following configuration:

1. Add to pom the follows dependencies:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
       <version>1.4</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
       <version>2.6</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Remove from yml:

   ```
   sprint:
     servlet:  
       multipart:
         enabled: true
         file-size-threshold: 2KB
         max-file-size: 10MB
         max-request-size: 10MB
   ```
3. Add to yml:

   ```
   server:
     tomcat:
       max-swallow-size: -1
       max-http-form-post-size: -1
   ```
4. And last but not least:

   ```
   @Bean
   public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
       CommonsMultipartResolver resolver
          = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
       resolver.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName());
       resolver.setMaxUploadSize(52428800L); //50MB
       resolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(52428800L); //50MB

       return resolver;
   }

   @ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
   public ResponseEntity<Object> handleFileUploadError(MaxUploadSizeExceededException ex) {
       return ResponseEntity.status(EXPECTATION_FAILED).body(
           CustomResponse.builder()
               .status(Status.ERROR)
               .message(ex.getMessage())
               .build());
   }

   // Where CustomResponse class is in my case:
   /**
     * The UploadResponse class
     * <p>
     * Contain the response body
     */
   @Getter
   @Builder(toBuilder = true)
   @AllArgsConstructor
   @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
   public class CustomResponse {
       /**
         * The status
         */
       private final Status status;
       /**
         * The message
         */
       private final String message;
       /**
         * The errors
         */
       private final Set<String> errors;
   }
   ```

Comment: The custom exception handler is nice, otherwise you get an ugly `500 Internal Server` error courtesy of Sprint's default exception handler. However, to increase the file size limit, all I had to do was add `spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10485760` to my `application.properties`. No need to create a custom `MultipartResolver` bean.