How to Prevent Spring Multipart File Uploads from Being Stored in Memory and Stream Directly to Disk?
I'm developing a Spring web application where I need to handle large file uploads using multipart requests. Currently, the entire file is stored in memory, and I would like to configure the application to stream files directly to disk, avoiding storage in memory.
 @PostMapping(consumes = [MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE])
 fun insert(
   @RequestPart
   file: MultipartFile
 )

During debugging, I found that memory usage occurs even before the request reaches the handler. This indicates that the file is fully loaded into memory at the early stages of request processing.
I tried using HttpServletRequest to directly access the stream and manage file uploads manually, but this still resulted in files being fully loaded into memory rather than in parts as they arrive over the network.
 @PostMapping(consumes = [MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE])    
 fun insert(request: HttpServletRequest)


As per docs, "spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold" property controls the threshold after which files are written to disk. Try setting a value greater than 0 bytes.  Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/appendix/application-properties/index.html#application-properties.web.spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold

Changing the file-size-threshold did not help, which makes sense since it is 0 by default, meaning that all files should be written to disk by default.

Check if commons-fileupload works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60564945/how-to-increase-file-size-upload-limit-in-spring-boot-using-embedded-tomcat

In my case, the problem was that Linux was trying to optimize file writing to the disk by writing them to RAM (so the RAM was used up not by my Java application). Therefore, I rewrote the solution so that it processes the file in a streaming manner instead of writing it to disk, and that helped.

To handle large file uploads in a Spring web application without loading the entire file into memory, you can use Spring's MultipartFile along with DataBufferUtils to stream the file directly to disk
Try configuring Spring to use a temporary storage location on disk rather than memory for file uploads. Here’s how:
Configure MultipartConfigElement: By setting a temporary file location.
Adjust application.properties: You can limit the maximum file size to prevent excessively large uploads from consuming too much memory.

Update your application.properties file to define these limits:

spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=50MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=200MB


You can also try this:

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.MultipartConfigFactory
import org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize
import javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement

@Configuration
class FileUploadConfig {

    @Bean
    fun multipartConfigElement(): MultipartConfigElement {
        val factory = MultipartConfigFactory()
        
        // Set the location where files will be stored temporarily
        factory.setLocation("/path/to/temp")
        
        // Set maximum file size
        factory.setMaxFileSize(DataSize.ofMegabytes(50))  // 50MB

        // Set total upload data size
        factory.setMaxRequestSize(DataSize.ofMegabytes(200))  // 200MB

        return factory.createMultipartConfig()
    }
}


As I mentioned in the question, by using debugging, I discovered that the file is written to memory before the request reaches my code. For example, in this case, the file will be stored in memory before the call to
val directory = Paths.get("path/to/directory")

alright, I'll change it

please accept the answer if it helped @user27758261
